# How to properly move In App Purchase download files from cache in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, zip

I am trying to set up an app with an In App Purchase that downloads content for 12 levels of a game when that respective pack is purchased.

I am stuck on how to properly move the downloaded images from the cache folder to the Documents folder. Here is my code so far:

```
func processDownload(sender: NSURL) {

    //Convert URL to String, suitable for NSFileManager
    var path:String = sender.path!
    path = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Contents")

    //Makes an NSArray with all of the downloaded files
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var files: NSArray!
    do {
        files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("Error finding zip URL", err.localizedDescription)
    }

    //For each file, move it to Library
    for file in files {

        let pathSource: String = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file as! String)
        let pathDestination: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

        //Remove destination files b/c not allowed to overwrite
        do {
            try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(pathDestination)
        }catch let err as NSError {
            print("Could not remove file", err.localizedDescription)
        }

        //Move file
        do {
           try fileManager.moveItemAtPath(pathSource, toPath: pathDestination)
            print("File", file, "Moved")
        }catch let err as NSError {
            print("Couldn't move file", err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything actually works just fine except for the errors that are printing from the two `do` statements. When trying to remove any existing files of the same name in the first `do` block, I get the following error:

```
Could not remove file “Library” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it.
```

This subsequently causes the next error from the next do statement to print because the original could not be removed.

Any ideas of why this is happening and how I can properly save the downloaded files elsewhere? Thanks.

Comment: The error says, you are trying to remove 'library' folder!, of course this is not allowed, perhaps you want to delete a subfolder out there? Can you confirm?

Comment: Oh I see that now. I was trying to see if the current "file" item was already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a proper working solution. This code will move all of the items in the downloaded zip folder to the `Library` directory.

```
func processDownload(sender: NSURL) {

    //Convert URL to String, suitable for NSFileManager
    var path: String = sender.path!
    path = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Contents")

    //Makes an NSArray with all of the downloaded files
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var files: NSArray!
    do {
        files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("Error finding zip URL", err.localizedDescription)
    }

    //For each file, move it to Library
    for file in files {

        let currentPath: String = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file as! String)
        var pathDestination: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
        pathDestination = pathDestination.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file as! String)

        //Move file
        do {
            try fileManager.moveItemAtPath(currentPath, toPath: pathDestination)
            print("File", file, "Moved")
        }catch let err as NSError {
            print("Couldn't move file", err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I can now make SKTextures in SpriteKit with these files like so:

```
var rippleTex = SKTexture(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("P06_ripple.png"))!)
```